# Core 2.1 SignalR and SQLDependency

Tags: signalr, sqldependency, asp.net-core-2.1

Is there any **Core 2.1** sample available for using SignalR with SQLDependency.
Did enable broker, etc. but never get any dependency onChange event firing. Just the event subscribe is triggered.
When the MS-SQL database table Cities changes on the back-end, I want to see the change reflected right-away on the client web page without having to refresh/reload the page.

//start the dependency when app start in ConfigureServices
SqlDependency.Start(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using SignalR_Test4.Data;
using SignalR_Test4.Hubs;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SignalR_Test4.Models
{
    public class CityRepository
    {
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IHubContext<CityHub> _hubcontext;
    public CityRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, IHubContext<CityHub> hubcontext)
    {
        _context = context;
        _hubcontext = hubcontext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<City> GetCities()
    {
        List<City> listOf = new List<City>();
        //listOf = _context.Cities;

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(GlobalVar.connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Cities", conn))
            {
                cmd.Notification = null;
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                dependency.OnChange += Dependency_OnChange;

                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conn.Open();


                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    listOf.Add(new City { Id = (string)reader["Id"], Name_en = (string)reader["name_en"], CountryId = (string)reader["CountryId"], Code = (string)reader["Code"] });
                }
            }
        }
        return listOf;
    }
    private void Dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            _hubcontext.Clients.All.SendAsync("GetCities");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Note of caution: Service Broker isn't available on most SQL Azure levels - so unless you have a managed instance be sure to first try you can even enable it before writing any code!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was within the line:

var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Id, Name_en, CountryId, Code from [dbo].Cities", conn)

It is required to use the field name (Not the *) and also the 2 part table name convention => [dbo].Cities

Comment: I'm using the same technique, however I get a error:When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance.